Argue that a subfamily of the inverse normal distribution is a affine subfamily of the full exponential family with $\lambda$ = $\mu^2$
Given the inverse normal distribution with density:
$$f_{\lambda, \mu}(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2\pi x^3}} \exp\left(-\frac{\lambda(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2 x}\right)$$
where $(\mu,\lambda)\in \mathbb{R}_+^2$
Let
$$\mathscr{P}=\{P_{\mu,\lambda}, \mu>0, \lambda>0\}$$
I've concluded that:
$$\theta=(\theta_1,\theta_2)^T=\left(\frac{\lambda}{2\mu^2},\frac{\lambda}{2}\right)^T$$
The exercise is now given as:
Now consider the subfamily of inverse normal distributions where the mean is equal to the variance, i.e. where $\lambda = \mu^2$.
Argue that the family is an affine subfamily of the full family and thus forms a regular exponential family of dimension 1
My attempt:
I want to create a subspace which only depends on $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.
Since $\theta_1 = \frac{\lambda}{2\mu^2}$ and $\theta_2 = \frac{\lambda}{2}$ i want them to depend on eachother:
$$\theta_1 = \frac{\lambda}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{\mu^2}=\frac{\lambda}{2\lambda}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Now insert $\theta_1$ into $theta_2$:
$$\theta_2 = \frac{\lambda}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \lambda = \theta_1 \cdot \lambda$$
Now i can create a subspace:
$$L=\{(\theta_1,\theta_2)|\theta_2=\theta_1\cdot \lambda\}$$
Now i've created this affine subspace, but i don't think i'm "allowed" to let it depend on another parameter, beside $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.
Does anybody have an idea how to complete this exercise?
